# I need a smart wallet contract (for testing)

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, wallets

The testing specification for my current task requires *Create 50 smart wallets that can hold M+ tokens*.

Thus I need a smart wallet contract. Please give me source of a simple smart wallet contract. It needs to support at least ERC-20 tokens receiving and sending (preferably also ERC-1155 tokens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```solidity
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract Wallet {
  address private owner;

  constructor ()
  payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  receive ()
  external payable {
    // Do nothing
  }

  function execute (address payable _to, uint _value, bytes memory _data)
  public payable returns (bytes memory) {
    require (msg.sender == owner);

    (bool success, bytes memory result) = _to.call {value: _value} (_data);

    require (success, string (result));
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have a bug: `_to` could be a non-payable smart contract.

Comment: Also compare to my own answer to my question. I copied special processing for `!success` case from another contract source.

Comment: Non-payable `_to` is not a problem, just pass `_value=0`.
Your `!success` handling is good, as well as mine, but I managed to avoid assembly.

Answer (score 0):

```solidity
//SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
// A simple smart wallet to be used for testing.
// Based on code from https://github.com/argentlabs/argent-contracts/blob/develop/contracts/wallet/BaseWallet.sol
pragma solidity ^0.7.1;

contract TestSmartWallet
{
    address payable owner;

    constructor(address payable _owner) payable {
        owner = _owner;
    }

    modifier ownerOnly {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You are not the owner of the smart wallet");
        _;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _amount) external ownerOnly {
        msg.sender.transfer(_amount);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Performs a generic transaction.
     * @param _target The address for the transaction.
     * @param _value The value of the transaction.
     * @param _data The data of the transaction.
     */
    function invoke(address _target, uint _value, bytes calldata _data) external ownerOnly returns (bytes memory _result) {
        bool success;
        (success, _result) = _target.call{value: _value}(_data);
        if (!success) {
            // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
            assembly {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
        // emit Invoked(msg.sender, _target, _value, _data);
    }

    receive() external payable {
    }
}
```

Is my code good?

Now I need advice on how to invoke it with Ethers.

Comment: `withdraw` is redundant, as `invoke (owner, amount, 0x)` could be used instead.